# How to recompile and run after modifying golang web code，Project build based on makefile

Tags: go, web

I am debugging an open source golang web project

https://github.com/studygolang/studygolang

Use the build command in the documentation "make build" and "make start",and then the project running.

The problem is when I modify some code，How to recompile the project。

I try “make reload”,but it not work. how to do ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply run `make build` again. You can read the `Makefile` located in the base directory of the project to learn what it does.